# ssh login successful, but scp password gives me "Permission denied"

Tags: ssh, permissions, scp, ssh-keygen

I'm trying to get some blogging software up on an organizational remote server.  I tried to set up a SSH Key but was having problems and decided that getting the blog up and running was more important than dealing with the SSH Key issue, so I `ssh-keygen -R remoteserver.com`.

Now I can successfully login with `ssh -v remoteuser@remoteserver.com` and the correct password.  Once logged in I can move around and read any file and directory that I should be able to read.

But when I try to edit an existing `-rw-r--r--` file with VIM, it shows up as read-only, if I try to edit permissions I get `chmod: file.ext: Operation not permitted`, and if I try to `scp` a new file from my local machine I'm prompted for the remote user's password, and then  get `scp: /home/path/to/file.ext: Permission denied`.

Since I didn't have any of these problems before I tried to set up the ssh key, I suspect these anomalies are a side effect of that, but I don't know how to troubleshoot this.  So what does a foolish server-newb, such as myself, need to do to get edit capability back as a remote user?

### Addendum 1:

My userids are different between my local machine and the remote server.

- For ssh I `ssh -v remoteuser@remoteserver.com`.

  - if I `whoami` I get `remoteuser`
- For scp I `scp file.ext remoteuser@remoteserver.com:/path/to/file.ext` from the local directory with `file.ext` while logged in as the local user.

  - if I `whoami` I get `localuser`

The `ls -l` for two different files I've tried scp:

```
-rw-r--r--@   1 localuser  localgroup    20 Feb 11 21:03 phpinfo.php
-rw-r--r--    1 root       localgroup     4 Feb 11 22:32 test.txt
```

The `ls -l` for the file I've tried to VIM:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 remoteuser  remotegroup      76 Jul 27  2009 info.txt
```

### Addendum 2:

In the past I've set up ssh-keys for git repositories.  I don't want to completely destroy them, so in an attempt to follow [a deer](https://serverfault.com/users/110415/a-deer)'s train of thinking I renamed my `~/.ssh/` to `~/.ssh-bak/`, then tested the different types of access.  The abridged version of the terminal commands and results is below; I think everything is working until the 8th line from the end.

*ssh -v*

```
localcomputer:~ localuser$ ssh -v remoteuser@remoteserver.com
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to remoteserver.com [###.###.###.###] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p2 FreeBSD-20110503
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p2 FreeBSD-20110503 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
The authenticity of host 'remoteserver.com (###.###.###.###)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##:##.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'remoteserver.com,###.###.###.###' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
remoteuser@remoteserver.com's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Last login: Sun Feb 12 18:00:54 2012 from 68.69.164.123
FreeBSD 6.4-RELEASE-p8 (VKERN) #1 r101746: Mon Aug 30 10:34:40 MDT 2010
```

*remote permissions*

```
[remoteuser@remoteserver /home]$ ls -l
total ###
-rw-r--r--   1 remoteuser remotegroup      76 Aug 12  2009 info.txt

[remoteuser@remoteserver /home]$ vim info.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                
~ {at the bottom of the VIM screen it tells me it's [read only]}                                                                                                                                                                                                    

[remoteuser@remoteserver /home]$ whoami 
remoteuser

[remoteuser@remoteserver /home]$ logout
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to remoteserver.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3872, received 12496 bytes, in 107.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 36.1, received 116.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```

*scp -v*

```
localcomputer:localdirectory name$ scp -v phpinfo.php remoteuser@remoteserver.com:/home/www/remotedirectory/phpinfo.php
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host remoteserver.com, user remoteuser, command scp -v -t /home/www/remotedirectory/phpinfo.php
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to remoteserver.com [###.###.###.###] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p2 FreeBSD-20110503
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p2 FreeBSD-20110503 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'remoteserver.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
remoteuser@remoteserver.com's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /home/www/remotedirectory/phpinfo.php
Sending file modes: C0644 20 phpinfo.php
Sink: C0644 20 phpinfo.php
scp: /home/www/remotedirectory/phpinfo.php: Permission denied
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 1456, received 2160 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2322.3, received 3445.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: What is your userid and id on the remote server, and what does `ls -l` show for the file you can't change?

Comment: when you say, you didn't have any problems before, what was the before situation?

Comment: @TomH - Before I started mucking around with ssh-keys I was able to edit files from the remote server and upload new files to the remote server.  I had problems implementing an ssh-key for the server in question, and when I tried to revert to the non-ssh-key login method I had previously been using, I lost write capability, but I can still read.

Comment: This is so bizarre.  Are you sure the filesystem is mounted read-write?  Run `mount`.  Can you also show the contents of the authorized_keys file?

Comment: @cjc I'm not familiar with `mount`.  If you meant something else, please let me know.

    [remoteuser@remoteserver ~]$ mount

    /dev/aacd0s1e on / (ufs, local, with quotas)
/dev/aacd0s1e on /skel (ufs, local, with quotas, read-only)
devfs on /dev (devfs)
/dev/aacd0s1d on /ports (ufs, local, read-only)
/dev/aacd1s1e on /backup (ufs, local, read-only)

Answer (score 3):

Your user account on the remote host probably does not have write permissions to the `/home/www/remotedirectory/` directory. You can test this by running:

`scp -v phpinfo.php remoteuser@remoteserver.com:/tmp/phpinfo.php`

Once this has been confirmed to work, you can set permissions and/or ownership on that directory. For a quick fix, `chmod 777 /home/www/remotedirectory/` as root will work, but this is not a secure solution. Depending on how the server is used, better would be to change the directory's group using `chgrp` to a group that you want all writers to that directory to be in and `chmod g+w /home/www/remotedirectory/`

Answer (score 2):

This is purely a permissions problem. The user "remoteuser" on "remoteserver" doesn't have permissions to write files to `/home/www/remotedirectory/phpinfo.php`. See this error in your `scp -v ..` commands output:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /home/www/remotedirectory/phpinfo.php
Sending file modes: C0644 20 phpinfo.php
Sink: C0644 20 phpinfo.php
scp: /home/www/remotedirectory/phpinfo.php: Permission denied
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
```

You can confirm this by ssh'ing into "remoteserver" just like you did originally and try and `touch` a file in this directory:

```
$ ssh remoteuser@remoteserver
```

*on remoteserver*

```
$ touch /home/www/remotedirectory/afile
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/www/remotedirectory/afile’: Permission denied
```

You can see the ownership of this directory with this command:

```
$ ls -ld /home/www/remotedirectory
drwxrwx---. 125 someuser somegroup 16384 Feb 22 14:03 /home/www/remotedirectory
```

So you'll need to either change the permissions here or take care to add "remoteuser" to the group "somegroup".

Answer (score 0):

well i do think your best option is to *make* it work with keys, but here are 2 options

try deleting `~/.ssh/authorized-keys` directory, or whole `~/.ssh/` to get rid of key leftovers

try setting up the keys properly and have fun with no passwords!  https://blogs.oracle.com/jkini/entry/how_to_scp_scp_and